# disable "Software Updater" automatic check and automatic download

Tags: 18.04

I thought I'd disabled software updater's automatic check/download features in the settings so I can just manually do it when I want to, and this works most of the time - but, every once in awhile it'll go off on its own right after I boot up, check for and download the updates without me telling it to, then ask me to install - why does this happen and can I get it to stop? Just want to do updating all myself before I shutdown and no longer need to use the machine.

REASON: very low-end laptop gets locked-up after I boot up when this happens as all its meager resources are maxed out (temps spike) and I can't do anything until it finishes - and you can't tell it's off doing it except for things begin to get choppy, hang, freeze for a bit, etc. and then you'e just stuck :-\

I know - get a better computer, heh, heh...

Comment: Need internet after bootup for my morning activities, so disabling it is not the answer. I can disable 'software updater totally by unchecking all three items under "Check Updates From" list and it never launches as there's nowhere to look - but then every time I need to update manually, I have to re-check these three, then let it look for updates - Should be some way more civilized ~ The info from the link says: "Update manager can only be stopped by removing it:" then gives: apt purge update-manager-core...
Do I REALLY want to just trash software updater all together (aka update manager)?

Comment: As per duplicate: `systemctl disable --now apt-daily{,-upgrade}.{timer,service}` disables the timer and the service so you can still do ot manually.

Comment: Will "systemctl disable --now apt-daily{,-upgrade}.{timer,service}" remove software updater? Or does it just simply disable it's ability to automatically update? (not interested in upgrades as 18.04LTS is my last stop with this old 32-bit laptop..) ie can I still run software updater to update or will I then have to use a terminal and run some cryptic commands?.
... and do I type it in just like indicated, or am I supposed to change the things in the "{ }" or something?